# locating div with paragraph in perl with HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl, html, tree, builder

I am trying to figure out the best way to use HTML::TreeBuilder in Perl to extract a few paragraphs of text from some HTML in a XML file.

I had it working using `$tree->address` (or so I thought) until I realized that not all entries are in the same order.

Without going though every single item in the list, it appears that each entry has several `<div>` elements, but only one of the `<div>`'s has `<p>` elements in it. And none of the `<div>`'s have classes, which would make this easy.

I have tried several different ways, and so for nothing seems to work in which I can extract the text in the  that I want.  I have looked at several different examples, but non of them really are close enough to what I am looking for.

It would be nice if something like this worked:

```
$bodyText = $tree->look_down( '_tag' => 'div' => 'p' );
```

But that gives me the error:

```
param list to look_down ends in a key!
```

Anyways, maybe someone can help point me in the right direction, I have been looking all night, and now my brain hurts.

Thanks!

John

Comment: Could you add an example snippet of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message makes sense. The `look_down` method expects a hash (which is a list of course). You are giving it three elements, so the last one is a key. Keep in mind that the `=>` is also called *fat comma* and is just a more readable way to write a `,`. It is a bit of an odd error message, though.

What you need to do is parse for `<div>`s first, and parse those for `<p>`s. You cannot do it in one go with HTML::TreeBuilder. You will get HTML::Element objects for each of the `<div>`s from the first `foreach`. Have them `look_down` for `<p>`s.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<DATA>);
foreach my $e ($tree->look_down(_tag => 'div')) {
  foreach my $f ($e->look_down(_tag => 'p')) {
    say $f->as_text;
  }
}

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<div>foo</div>
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
<div>foo2</div>
<div>foo3</div>
<div><p>hello again</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

With the vanilla form of [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder), this is best done using a code reference as a criterion of `look_down`. The subroutine will be called for each node in the tree that passes all previous criteria, and a node will be retained if the subroutine returns a true value.

This program shows its use. The anonymous subroutine uses grep to check the children of the node that is passed to it, counting all elements that have a `p` tag. The array `@divs` then contains all `div` elements that have a `p` child element. You may want to ensure that the `@divs` contains exactly one element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $doc = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<<__HTML__);
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
<div><p>paragraph</p></div>
<div>content</div>
<div>content</div>
__HTML__

my @divs = $doc->look_down(
  _tag => 'div', 
  sub { grep { ref eq 'HTML::Element' and  $_->tag eq 'p' } $_[0]->content_list }
);

say scalar @divs, " found:\n";
say $divs[0]->as_HTML('<>&', '  ');
```

**output**

```
1 found:

<div>
  <p>paragraph</div>
```

However, it is very much neater to employ the enhanced [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath), which allows the data to be addressed using XPath expressions. This allows `look_down` to be replaced with a `findnodes` call:

```
my @divs = $doc->findnodes('//div[p]');
```

and the result is identical to that of the code above.

Comment: Trying your first example, I received the following error:`Can't call method "isa" without a package or object reference at ...` but 'm not sure why?

Comment: @JohnB: I apologize. I forgot you can't call `isa` on an empty string. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use **XPath** for this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<DATA>);
foreach my $e ( $tree->findnodes('//div/p') ) {

    say $e->as_text;
}

__DATA__
<html>
<body>
<div>foo</div>
<div><p>hello world</p></div>
<div>foo2</div>
<div>foo3</div>
<div><p>hello again</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Web::Query 'wq';
print wq("<html><div><p>I'm trapped under a hat</p></div><div /><div /><div /><div /><div />")
        ->find('div p')->text;
```

Comment: Very neat. An explanation would be nice, though. ;-)